# How to separate rows from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a very large matrix of size 16384 x 16. I need to obtain a 512 x 512 matrix from it. The matrix should be joined as follows,
Say L the matrix of size 16384 x 16.By default L is arranged as below

```
    L = [L1
         L2
         L3
         .
         .
         L32].
```

I need to obtain L such that,G(ie;the new 512x512 matrix)

```
     G = [L1L2...L32]
```

Here each L is a 512x16 matrix. Initially I tried for a 32x32 matrix and obtained the results correctly but I was not able to do it for a larger matrix. What should I do? The following is the code I had used

```
       W1 = 32;
       Ans1 = L(1:W1,:);
       Ans2 = L(W1+1:end,:);
       G = [Ans1,Ans2];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) & [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
cutlen = 512;  %// "Cut" after every cutlen rows
G = reshape(permute(reshape(L,cutlen,[],size(L,2)),[1 3 2]),cutlen,[]);
```

Comment: May i know why we should use [1 3 2] and size(L,2) ?

Comment: @Roshni191 Well the `size(L,2)` is used to reshape the input array into a 3D array and then we permute (rearrange the dimensions) with exchanging dimensions between `3` (dim-3) and `2`(rows). The final step is to reshape back to a 2D array.